# object Event appears in input field on focusout

Tags: vue.js, dom, focusout

I am working on VueJS app that allows to edit json file with specific data. I have two similar components: AliasEntry and EquipmentEntry. The second is used to manipulate array of objects and seems to work fine. I can add, delete and edit fields. But AliasEntry, which serves arrays of aliases (strings) behaves weird and crashes: When I click on input with actual string in it and edit it, changes are updated in props. But when i click out of input, it's content is replaced by "[object Event]" and performing any action crashes app with error "Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': Event object could not be cloned."

Here is code of AliasEntry component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input 
    :value="item" 
    @input="(event) => handleAliasUpdate(event)"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { toRaw } from 'vue'
export default {
  props: {
    item: String
  },
  methods: {
    handleAliasUpdate(event){
      const record = structuredClone(toRaw(event.target.value))
      this.$emit('change', record)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I tried to add toRaw, because it helped earlier, but i am at loss right now.
Note: i suppose this error ("Failed to execute 'structuredClone'...) happens in containing component.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to how you're handling the event object in your `handleAliasUpdate` method.

Use `event.target.value` directly without `toRaw`, since `event.target.value` is already the raw value you want.

Remove the `structuredClone` function, as it's unnecessary in this context and might be causing the error.

You can do it like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input 
      :value="item" 
      @input="handleAliasUpdate"
    >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: String
  },
  methods: {
    handleAliasUpdate(event) {
      const newValue = event.target.value;
      this.$emit('change', newValue);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I hope this helps you.